# How can I know which is the oldest tag of Physics Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, history

How can I know which is the oldest tag of Physics Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the database IDs were assigned sequentially, use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/edit/1776354).

Comment: And to keep other inquiring minds from needing to run the query (which goes faster for only the top 10): the answer is quantum-spin

Comment: not sure all tags are returned.  For instance the  tag: coherent-states is not listed.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It lists the top few. [tag:coherent-states] has id 1994, see https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/edit/1776411

Comment: Presumably the first tag is the alphabetically-first tag on /q/1 on the site. Which, [indeed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/1/revisions), should be quantum-spin.